# Is this for loop infinite?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In this code, is this for loop that traverses the bool array infinite?

I'm having trouble understanding because when an element in the arr_bool array becomes true, it displays the corresponding element, yet the for loop is terminated and TradingView continues to read the code down.

```
arr_bool = array.from(false, false, false, false, false, false)
arr_string = array.from('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6')
arr_new = array.new_string(0)

for i = 0 to array.size(arr_bool) - 1 by 1
    if bool(array.get(arr_bool, i))
        array.push(arr_new, array.get(arr_string, i))

var tab = table.new(position=position.top_right, columns=2, rows=10)
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(tab, 0, 0, text='Col', text_size=size.large, bgcolor=color.new(color.gray,80), text_color=color.white)

if barstate.isrealtime
    if array.size(arr_new) > 0
        for i = 0 to array.size(arr_new) - 1 by 1
            table.cell(tab, 0, i+1, text=str.tostring(array.get(arr_new, i)), text_color=color.blue, bgcolor=color.new(color.blue,80))
```

Comment: Why for loop with clear start and end indexes should be infinite?

Comment: And about which `for` you ask as there are 2 of them

Answer (score 0):

The for loop in the given code snippet does not appear to be infinite. It iterates through the elements of the `arr_bool` array, and when an element in the `arr_bool` array becomes true, it displays the corresponding element. However, the for loop terminates after iterating through the array, and the code then continues to execute the subsequent lines.

Here's a breakdown of the code:

1. It initializes three arrays: `arr_bool`, `arr_string`, and `arr_new`.
2. It then iterates through the `arr_bool` array. If the value at the current index is `true`, it adds the corresponding element from `arr_string` to `arr_new`.
3. After the loop, it creates a table called `tab`, and if it's the last bar state, it sets the first cell of the table.
4. If it's a real-time bar state and the `arr_new` array has elements, it iterates through `arr_new` and adds the elements to the table.

In summary, the for loop in question is not infinite. It iterates through the `arr_bool` array, processes the elements based on their values, and then the code continues to execute the subsequent lines.

Comment: Thank you for these explanations... but if the loop is finished and the code continues to execute the following lines, then why if 1 or more elements of the "arr_bool" array become "true" then it displays the corresponding elements of the "arr_string" array?